# Will setting up a VPN prevent others from seeing what is on the network?

Tags: networking, vpn, wifi

I have a computer in the house that is used for a work from home call center business.  Part of their contract is for nothing else to be connected to the network (wired or wifi) during work hours.  Due to the fact that there are multiple people in this house that still wish to be able to use the internet during these hours we were considering various options for this.  I know of the existence of programs that allow someone to access a computer remotely, and potentially even see the connections to the router, would putting the work computer on its own VPN protect against that?

Comment: You need to talk with your IT department.

Comment: That I unfortunately cannot do.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, what they want is for there to be no other connections active on the computer you will be using for business.  In other words, it should not have any connectivity to any other computers or devices in your house.  It should have no other routes to the outside world other than through the corporate VPN.

A VPN on one computer should not have any impact on what other users in your house, behind your same firewall, do on the network.

To be 100% sure, however, any clarification questions should be asked of the folks in charge of the corporate network.

Comment: Is there anything special that needs to be done in regards to setting up the VPN from the corporate side or can it all be done from the home end?  I'm currently researching it and trying to understand all this but I'm not even really sure where to begin.  I know our router has VPN capabilities at least.

Comment: You'll need to install client software on the computer that is compatible with their corporate VPN, *or* you can do it on the router as well. If the router, then it *would* affect everyone in the house.

Answer (score 0):

The corporate people will need to tell you how you're needing to connect to the VPN. Ipsec is common and so is openVPN but they need to tell you what VPN method they're using. You should not need to do any special configuration on your system to connect.